# Browserify eslint require(...).pathToFileURL is not a function

Tags: node.js, eslint, require, browserify, linter

I am trying to bundle the code below using browserify

```
const { ESLint } = require('eslint');
console.log(ESLint);
```

And when I include the generated bundle in a html file, I get this error.

**Uncaught TypeError: require(...).pathToFileURL is not a function**

When I checked the generated bundle I found that it contained require() function. Browserify should recursively replace all require() and combine them into one file, right? I am using Node.js version 14.15.1 and eslint version 8.13.0.

[image: bundle.js]

Is there something I've missed. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you maybe add a stack trace? Also, what version of ESLint? What version of Node.js?

Comment: @GOTO0 I have update the question.

Comment: I have the same issue when using Webpack 5, "require('url').pathToFileURL is not a function". Haven't solved it yet, but it's because "node:url" exports the pathToFileURL function but the npm package "url" doesn't export it.

Comment: this could be a long shot, but are you running an ancient version of node? try upgrading it.